# SAP DBTech JDBC: [4321]: only secure connections are allowed

Tags: java, jpa, hana, sap-business-technology-platform

I am unable to create a connection with SAP Cloud Foundry HANA service from my Spring boot app. I have given JPA properties values as the information is provided in HANA HDI service binding in SCP CF but getting following error from my Sample Spring boot:

> SAP DBTech JDBC: [4321]: only secure connections are allowed"

SAP CF HANA service is enforcing security is there any standard way to make connection with Spring boot to SAP HANA CF service?

Just to add connectivity is not working when making a connection in Springboot app via `application.yml` file by setting JPA properties, but was able to make a connection in a servlet using connection object by looking up the driver class manually via code.

How I can make a successful connection via JPA properties in `application.yml` file ?

Comment: Are you sure the error is not that you need to use HTTPS/SSL connections ?

Comment: hans cf service is expecting ssl connection on jdbc ,:Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.JDBCDriverException: SAP DBTech JDBC: [4321]: only secure connections are allowed

Comment: Hello Experts any help will be very helpful if anyone has done any HANA cf service connectivity over sap cloud foundry with spring boot with JPA ,please suggest some pointers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue seems to be known to SAP:

https://github.com/SAP/spring-cloud-sap/issues/8

There is at least a workaround listed on the end of the page, which might help.

Answer (score 0):

try this for your data source url in application.yml:

```
jdbc:sap://{host}:{port}?encrypt=true&validateCertificate=false&currentschema={schema}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the exact same error.
Check your URL. In my case the URL looked similar to this one:

```
jdbc:sap://<host>:<port>?encrypt=true\u0026validateCertificate=true\u0026currentschema=D006A421632F47ED8A2C9346D28B67C2
```

Note the two occurrences of `\u0026` escape sequences in the URL.
These should be `&` instead.
Once I changed them to `&` chars, it worked.

As previous answers noted, `encrypt=true` needs to be in the URL - but it won't be found if the `&` character is escaped.

If the URL contains the escape sequences, I would say it qualifies as a SAP HANA bug. Also, the error message is not really helping much. A message of `Could not find encrypt=true in URL. Only secure connections are allowed!` would have helped finding this more easily.